# SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I need to perform replication on MS SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition. The goal is, that I have several databases (for example 4 instances of SQL Server) and each must act as publisher to other sites. I know, that merge replication model of subscriber - publisher - subscriber is possible, but it doesn't suit me. I need to maintain replication process between other machines when no matter which server is down, so all other servers will have actual data.

Is it even possible? And if yes, can You point me to something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing peer-to-peer replication. Read up on it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Yep, that's true. But, my client has MS SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition and peer to peer replication doesn't work, as far as I'm concerned.